# Cannot get current page ID with VF page in Community

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-controller

I built a VF page that is used in a community and I am trying to grab the current page id using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')`. For some reason, this always returns null. If I use a standard controller with extension, then I can see the value just fine on a page layout outside of the community, only issue is with user in the community pages. Could this be some type of profile setting that is off or is there a different way to grab this value in community?

This is a custom object, the record id is shown in the url. I have tried using both a custom controller and an extension with the standard controller from the custom app object.

Additional Details: The community walks the user through a series of screens which create the Application record. I am using a workaround right now where I query the last modified Application by the use since this will be the record that is created as the user is walked though the screens. This just seems like a less than optimal workaround.

```java
    public class OnlineAppController2{
   
    
    public String getName(){
        App__c app2 = [SELECT ID, Name FROM App__c WHERE ID=: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        return app2.Name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more detail.  Is this a Visualforce / Tabs community template?  How are you calling the VF page and what object are you using?

Comment: Added additional details. Hope that helps.